# JpaRepository failing to do multiple updates in the same transaction

Tags: hibernate, transactions, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm having a problem where multiple updates in a single transaction are causing a failure due to optimistic locking, which doesn't make sense to me since it's in the same transaction.
Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
@Entity
public class MyObj {
    @Id
    private String myKey;

    @Column("val")
    private Integer val;

    @Version
    private Date lastModDate;
}

public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository<MyObj, String> {

}

@Component
public class MyComponent {

    @Resource
    MyRepo repo;

    @Transactional
    public void doUpdates() {
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            MyObj obj = repo.findOne("thekey");
            obj.setVal(i);
            repo.save(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

The call to repo.save() fails on the 2nd attempt due to a hibernate StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction.

This doesn't make sense to me since it should be in the same transaction as i'm doing them both in the same method within the for loop.

Am I completely wrong here or should this thing work properly and maybe I have some configuration problem?

I've also tried calling saveAndFlush() instead of just save() but same results.

Comment: may be its happen with hibernate connection please try entityManager.merge(entity); instead of save, dont need to flush.
i think it will work..

Comment: It must be something else. The code you've posted is OK, I've tried it with success. Could you post your transaction related Spring configuration? Btw `@Resource` is javax and not Spring annotation - it works, but I wouldn't mix it. Try sticking with `@Autowired`

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have exactly the same problem.